# Angular - How to Prevent Destroying Scope w/ State Change

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angular-ui-router

**Disclaimer** I am not looking for a simple parent/child ui-router relationship

I am looking for a solution where I am on one page and I can change to any arbitrary state without removing the contents/listeners of the previous state.

**Use Case:**

- User is on a splash page
- clicks on login modal
- Url changes from `/splash` to `/login`
- New modal opens up, the splash page contents in the background do not disappear

The idea is that I wouldn't need to be on any specific child state to have this work.

Comment: http://christopherthielen.github.io/ui-router-extras/example/stickymodal/index.html#/  I wrote sticky states to handle this use case.

Comment: This is great Chris! Exactly what I'm looking for + more. Set is an the answer and I'll accept it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this with UI-Router Extras "Sticky States".

Here is the UI-Router Extras modal demo: http://christopherthielen.github.io/ui-router-extras/example/stickymodal/#/

---

Add UI-Router Extras:

```
  <script src="https://rawgit.com/christopherthielen/ui-router-extras/0.0.10/release/ct-ui-router-extras.js"></script>
```

---

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', ['ui.router', 'ct.ui.router.extras', 'ui.bootstrap']);
```

---

Add a named ui-view for the app and one for the modal

```
<body>
  <div ui-view="app"></div>
  <div ui-view="modal"></div>
</body>
```

---

Mark your app state as `sticky`.  The effect is that you can navigate from any `app.*` state to the modal state... instead of exiting that state, it will only "inactivate" it, and it remains in the DOM.

```
$stateProvider
.state("app", {
  template: "<div ui-view></div>",
  sticky: true,
```

Comment: Thanks for this wonderful addition to UI router, Chris! Is there any way to manually destroy specified sticky state? I'm having a situation where I need to "close" a tab, and don't want its scope data to linger in the memory.

Comment: Inject `$stickyState` service, then use `$stickyState.reset('state.name')`

Answer (score 0):

You can't be on many states at once. Modals have their own scope, to which you can pass your own stuff and usually modals are not associated with a state switch.

1. Reconsider that a modal should require a state switch
2. Modals have their own scope, destroying which doesn't affect the scope of the place from where they were called in any way.